# Sorting based on first column and then next column

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have a dictionary that needs to be sorted. I want to sort the dict based on the values. And as a next step, if two keys have same value, I want to sort based on the lexicographic values of keys.

I tried this.

```
>>> l
{'a': 5, 'aa': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 7}
>>> sorted(l)
['a', 'aa', 'b', 'c']
>>> sorted(l.items())
[('a', 5), ('aa', 5), ('b', 7), ('c', 1)]
>>> sorted(l.items(), reverse=True)
[('c', 1), ('b', 7), ('aa', 5), ('a', 5)]
>>> sorted(l.items(), key=l.get, reverse=True)
[('a', 5), ('aa', 5), ('c', 1), ('b', 7)]
>>> l
{'a': 5, 'aa': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 7}
>>> 5>7
False
>>> sorted(l.items(), key=l.get, reverse=True)
[('a', 5), ('aa', 5), ('c', 1), ('b', 7)]
>>> sorted(l, key=l.get, reverse=True)
['b', 'a', 'aa', 'c']
>>> s=sorted(l, key=l.get, reverse=True)
>>> s
['b', 'a', 'aa', 'c']
>>> s.sort()
>>> s
['a', 'aa', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you're searching for something like that:

```
d = {'a': 5, 'aa': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 7}
result = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('c', 1), ('a', 5), ('aa', 5), ('b', 7)]
```

---

If you want the values to be ascending order and the second sort to be in descending order, you can do something like that:

```
d = {'a': 5, 'aa': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 7}
result = sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('c', 1), ('aa', 5), ('a', 5), ('b', 7)]
```

For more information about sorting, see the [Sorting Howtos.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

---

If you have a list of tuples that contains only strings, you can do something like that:

```
l = [('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'spam'), ('baz', 'egg')]

result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], [-ord(c) for c in x[1]]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('baz', 'egg'), ('foo', 'spam'), ('foo', 'bar')]
```

Comment: Yes, Thats is what I am looking for. Thanks, I will test the answer and accept it.

Comment: As a side note, the lambda function can be subsituted by the equivalent, more efficient, slightly less obvious function `operator.itemgetter(1, 0)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, Now that you say it, I just tested lambda function for multiplying list elements. Turns out for loops are far more efficient in Python that lambda function! Thanks for reminding that again.

Comment: @segfolt, I wanted add another question here, the values should be ascending order while the second sort should be in descending order. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @segfolt, I  just have another question here. I found what I was looking for. In this case, keys and values are strings and nums respectively. I can easily do -x[1] and arrive at the solution. However, if both keys and values are strings, then how to achieve sorting on column in ascending order and the other on descending order.

Comment: @segfolt, Awesome thank you very much! I am going to accept the answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

Return both the value and the key, in that order:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda k: (l[k], k))
```

for just the keys, or

```
sorted(l.items(), key=lambda i: i[::-1])
```

for key-value pairs; the `[::-1]` negative-step slice reverses the value and the key for sorting.

This sorts first on the value, then uses the key if the values are equal.

Result:

```
>>> l = {'a': 5, 'aa': 5, 'c': 1, 'b': 7}
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda k: (l[k], k))
['c', 'a', 'aa', 'b']
>>> sorted(l.items(), key=lambda i: i[::-1])
[('c', 1), ('a', 5), ('aa', 5), ('b', 7)]
```

For a mixed direction sort, *negate* the values, and reverse the sort:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0]), reverse=True)
[('c', 1), ('aa', 5), ('a', 5), ('b', 7)]
```

Negating the numbers causes them to be sorted in descending order while the keys retain ascending order; reversing then swaps that to ascending and descending, respectively.

Comment: I wanted add another question here, the values should be ascending order while the second sort should be in descending order. Is it possible to do that?